# Formula to determine if growth is increasing/decreasing, smooth, lumpy, etc

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have some results data in around 10 columns (sample in CSV below) that I would like to run a formula or formulas per row to determine if the trend is

- reasonably steady/predictable, or lumpy (no straight lines expected)
- generally trending upwards or downwards over the period
- changing trend towards the end (most recent 3 months) or continuing it's trend

As the sample shows below, some rows do not have all the data, but still need a determination of the general trend and consistency of the results.

A graph would display these easily enough, but I have thousands of rows to compare, so is not efficient or feasible.

I've tried a few formulas such as trend, growth, stddev, avedev, but I suspect I might have to use them in combination, which is currently beyond me. I feel like using the percentage difference between neighboring cells will help standardise the results to a degree, rather than the value of each cell. If the percentages are all positive then the trend is upward, but that's the best I've been able to come up with that I'm happy gives a clear answer.

I'm using google sheets, but might be able to convert an Excel formula.
Any suggestions?

```
May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb
11.65,11.79,11.96,12.26,12.71,12.6,12.71,13.6,14.1,14.7
0.57,0.65,0.33,0.89,1.03,0.74,1.35,0.81,2.13,2.15
1.85,1.88,1.84,1.92,2.07,2.24,2.56,2.74,2.85,2.92
,,,0.66,0.72,0.78,1.33,1.43,1.47,1.52
,,,,0.64,0.6,0.56,0.55,0.3,
,8.97,8.54,10.46,11.44,8.06,7.42,7.86,7.66,7.1
2.67,1.53,1.84,2.43,2.94,3.43,4.04,7.46,6.25,9.09
```

- Row 1 - Smooth growth
- Row 2 - Lumpy growth
- Row 3 - Growth
- Row 4 - Growth
- Row 5 - Declining
- Row 6 - Lumpy. Past 3m decline.
- Row 7 - Growth. Past 3m lumpy

Comment: Well if row data is independent, remove banks. Make a line chart with each row to see the trend, work from there. The question is currently too unspecific.

Comment: I have a sense that this isn't a programming question per se, but a statistical question about "how" to calculate a trend based on the data that you have. Is that right? If it is, then maybe there's another stackexchange group that would be better able to help you.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output and math equation how you got there

Comment: Sorry for the delay in extra clarity. Have been away. 
I've added the type of results I'm hoping to see for each row of data (either in 1 cell or in 2-4 cells)